# Apply TextDecorations to a CollapsibleSection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have CollapsibleSection objects that are dynamically being created in code.  I would like to simply say:

```
CollapsibleSection section = new CollapsibleSection();
section.TextDecoration = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
```

This is proving more difficult that I thought.  Does anyone have some insight on a simple way to strikethrough the entire content of a collapsible section?

---

I'm missing something still. Here's what I have so far:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDecorationProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TextDecoration", typeof(TextDecoration), 
   typeof(CollapsibleSection));
```

In my method where I am creating my CollapsibleSection I have this:

```
CollapsibleSection cs = new CollapsibleSection(); 
if (flagIsTrue) { 
  section.SetValue(TextDecorationProperty, TextDecorations.Strikethrough); 
}
```

These CollapbsibleSection's are used to populate a FlowDocument.

I get this exception: 'System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection' is not a valid value of property 'TextDecoration'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the attached property to not throw an error by changing the parameter from `typeof(TextDecoration)` to `typeof(TextDecorationCollection)` but the property never seemed to actually attach to the `UIElement` so I bagged it and just ended up setting the properly at the Paragraph level.

Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attached property.  This can be done in Code or XAML

```xml
<Expander Header="test" TextBlock.TextDecorations="Strikethrough">
    <TextBlock>This is some random text</TextBlock>
</Expander>
```

Comment: This gave me a nudge in the right direction but I'm still not quite there.  Take a look at my edit.